# Creating COM using ATL in C++ from VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, com

Trying to create simple COM library using ATL in Visual Studio 2012. 
I do:

```
 New ATL Project
 Welcome to the ATL Project Wizard
 Next
 Application Settings - no change (DLL)
 Next
 Finish
```

[image]

Got a lot of files:

[image]

Trying to understand where to add simple function that can be called by COM user. I found only one place where I can add function using wizard:

[image]

But I see that something is missing there regarding parameters selection like in,out,retval.
[image]

And I was hoping that after adding new function at least IDL file will be updated too, but this not happened.

What is the way of creating simple COM class using ATL from Visual C++ from VS2012 ?

Comment: Write the IDL by hand and then update the classes to match.

Comment: COM methods are exposed via interfaces, which are implemented by objects. You need to add object first (Add ATL Simple Object) using similar wizard). Then you add methods to interface, which will be created for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a new class
   [image]
2. Fill in fields
   [image]
   [image]

After this step `SomeObject.h`, `SomeObject.cpp` files will be created and added to your solution, the `ISomeObject` interface declaration will be added to the `.idl` file.

3. Go to Class View (the combination ctrl+shift+C by default), select `ISomeObject`, add a new method
   [image]
4. Fill in fields
   [image]

After this step the `someMethod` will be added to `.idl` file, `.h` file and `.cpp` file. All you have to do - is to write an implementation of `someMethod` in `.cpp` file.

Comment: I have created dll using your recomendation and have registered wit regsvr32 in 32bit WinXP OS, but I can't find its registration info. I use PowerShell script from http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/27/pstip-get-a-list-of-all-com-objects-available/

Comment: It is in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ATLProject1.SomeProject.1` key. The PS1 script is incorrect. It should match `^\w+\.\w+(?:$|.\d+)`.

Comment: Fine, I have `ATLProject1.SomeProject.1`. I suppose `ATLProject1.SomeProject` is what we have entered in ProgID, but what `1` at the end means?

Comment: It means the version of COM object. `ATLProject1.SomeProject\CurVer = ATLProject1.SomeProject.1`, `ATLProject1.SomeProject.1\CLSID = {GUID}`. So can create the object like `var o = new ActiveXObject('ATLProject1.SomeProject');` in a script and you've got the actual (current) version of your COM object.